# Why is guava's AbstractMultiset not public?

Tags: java, guava, multiset

I tried to write a class that extends guava's `AbstractMultiset` but I saw that it isn't a public class.  Why is that?  
Is there a different class that I should be extending? The other similar classes that I know (`AbstractCollection`, `AbstractSet`, etc) *are* public.

Comment: Nothing against the question, but IMO, the best(read *correct*) answer to this question can come from a *dev* working in the *Guava division*, at *Google*.

Comment: There are such developers here on Stackoverflow, so...

Comment: I never claimed that we won't get an answer or something. I just said that the best answer would be from.. we already have [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) btw! :)

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that the answer is "it was an oversight".

There is an outstanding issue to correct this in the issue tracker: http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=157.  Nobody has argued against fixing this, but it just hasn't happened.

Comment: If you look at the comments now, there _are_ arguments against fixing this.

Comment: It is also worth noting that the dev team appears to have come around to agreeing that making the baseclass public >>is<< the best solution for the OP's use-case.  Anyway, it is worth reading the comments.